# Can I create an AWeber broadcast with Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, aweber

i'm having trouble with AWeber's not-being-able-to-format-rss-pubDate failure when creating a blog broadcast template, and i can't even style an {!rss_item_description} properly if it contains both an image and a paragraph (since GMail does not allow external css, or  blocks either).

So i'm thinking if creating an html message via drupal, and sending the html code (with all things properly styled) to AWeber as a broadcast message every end of the week is possible.

I'm hoping for any API thingies or modules present but any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contacted Aweber's support and they told me the only way to create a broadcast is via logging into the aweber site. There's no api for that yet. :|